# insert special character in my sql server database

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

ANSWER :

Sorry about the this sort of question guys, I assumed that it wouldn't work if I directly enter the special character into my string in query but it does. so all you need to do is locate the special character, copy it and paste it into your query and it works :)

---

folks,

QUESTION CHANGED:

I want to enter a ascii character in the database which is the standard trademark symbol (®) using a direct query and have it read correctly ! how can i do this ?

PREVIOUS QUESTION:
how can i enter a special character in SQL Server in varchar column... ® (there is also a line below this symbol which I am unable to paste here) so that it is read correctly.

Also, I am unable to find the character sequence for that symbol any places where I can look for ?

The symbol is standard ® symbol which hangs on the top and there is a line below it just like an underscore.

Thanks

EDIT 1: I am talking about a direct query to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this T-SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(UnicodeCol)
VALUES(nchar(0x00AE))
```

`®` is the Unicode character with code `0x00AE`

But of course - since this is a Unicode character, the column you're inserting into **must** be of type `NVARCHAR` (**not** `VARCHAR`)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to **Unicode NCR format** before you store to database, or just encode it with related functions of the language you are using , like JavaScript's `encodeuricomponent`, PHP's [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am talking about a direct query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'N' ahead of data.
This query might be helpful to you.

```
insert into product_master(product_name) values(N'कंप्यूटर')
```